# Node-Mongo: Query nearby users geoNear Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, geojson

I am using mongo `$geoNear` for getting nearby users, i am getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"no geo indices for geoNear\" }"
    }
}
```

My Model or the Schema is as below

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        fbId: String,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        picture: {type:String,default:''},
        email: {type: String, lowercase: true},
        platform: {type: String, emun:['ios','android']},
        deviceId: String,
        fcmToken: String,
        location: {
            type: {type:String,default:'Point'},
            coordinates: {type:[Number],index:'2dsphere',default:[0,0]}
        }
    }
);
```

In the controller i am querying for nearby user by passing my current location

```
//Route
https://example.com/api/v1/user/:id/nearByUsers/:lat/:long

//controller
const nearByUsers = await User.aggregate([
    {
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [longitude,latitude]},
            "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
            "minDistance": minDistanceInMeters,
            "maxDistance": maxDistanceInMeters,
            "spherical": true,
            "query": { "location.type": "Point" }
        }
    }
]);

return response(res, nearByUsers);
```

i guess this error comes if there is no data to query for, i'm not sure though

looking forward for much needed help

thank you

Comment: $geoNear requires a [geospacial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/) on the location field: `db.collection.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )`

Comment: @Xavier Guihot thank you for your response really appreciate it, should i mention add the `location : "2dsphere"` in my query or?

Comment: @Xavier Guihot i am using the index, my schema.`coordinates: {type:[Number],index:'2dsphere',default:[0,0]}`, if this is what you are referring to.